# Complicated grouping SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite, group-by, sum

I'm making a project on android studio using SQLite and i had a problem

I have a table similar to the following:

```
M   N
1   100
1   -50
1   10
1   -20
2   100
2   -15
3   40
```

What query will get me the following result:

```
M   Total   TotalPositive   TotalNegative
1   40      110             -70
2   85      100             -15
3   40      40              0
```

I've wrote the following query:

```
SELECT M, SUM(N) AS 'Total' FROM tablename GROUP BY N;
```

i could only get the M and the Total part and i have no idea how i can get the sums of positive and negative values only. can you please help me with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: obviously you have to group by M and use something like `SUM(CASE WHEN N > 0 THEN N ELSE 0 END) AS TotalPositive` and so on  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by `M` instead of `N`. You can use `CASE` to do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    M,
    sum(N) total_sum,
    sum(case when N > 0 then N else 0 end) total_positive,
    sum(case when N < 0 then N else 0 end) total_negative
from your_table
group by M;
```